# HtmlUnit set download location

Tags: selenium, htmlunit

Currently I am executing selenium script with HtmlUnit. How can I set the Download location for the zip file downloaded at the time of test script execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ChromeDriver in headless mode. You just need to add options as headless as below:

```
   chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
```

The full code in Java will appear as below:

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Workspace\\JmeterWebdriverProject\\src\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");
 ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
 chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
 chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
 driver.get("https://google.com");
```

You can use ChromeDriver to set download in a specific path by below code:

```
String downloadFilepath = "/path/to/download";
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

Comment: I used to run scripts on Linux machine will chrome driver work on remote machine

Comment: of course you can run and use chrome driver in remote as well.. just your remote machine should have the chrome driver binary in place .. You can download chrome binary as per your OS from below location :- https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.32/

Comment: refer :- http://www.qatestingtools.com/forum-topic/Selenium_Chrome-Driver_Remote-Webdriver